# How to handle 302 redirect requests in axios?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, axios, http-status-code-302

I am using reactjs library for the frontend. I will be making a post request using axios to the backend, the backend responds with status code 302. Expected behaviour is that it will make a redirect to that URL. But it is not happening.
I have searched through various posts. Some say that axios will not do the page redirection.

So not sure how to handle 302 redirects in axios. Help needed.

Comment: I am assuming you are using react router for routing.
There is a history object provided by the react router.
You need to use 'push' function of that object.

Comment: I am not getting any URL that i can manually redirect to. Redirection is happening in backend which sends 302

Comment: The almost same question was asked here and answered : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63574485/how-to-get-the-redirected-response-from-axios/63575061

Comment: The almost same question was asked here and answered : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63574485/how-to-get-the-redirected-response-from-axios/63575061