# How to get the redirected response from axios?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I don't think there is a problem with the **request** because I have used the same request for *posting a new character* and it succeded.
I think the problem is with the **response**.

#### Backend using Express and Node

I have an API route which *updates a character*.

```js
router.put('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    Promise.all([
        updateAbilities(id, req.body.abilities, next),
        updateCharacter(id, req.body.name, req.body.img, next),
        updateShows(id, req.body.shows, next)
    ])
        .then(values => console.log(values, 'are the values received at put request'))
        .then(() => res.redirect('/' + id))
        .catch(err => next(err));
})
```

When I am sending the request using **Postman**, I am getting the perfect response.

[Image of postman response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8fZ3.png)

#### Frontend in React App using Axios

I am performing the same request on a React App using **Axios**.

```js
export async function updateOne(inputs, cid) {
    inputs = {
        name: "green latern 2",
        abilities: "ring, superpower",
        shows: "justice league",
        img: "an image",
    };
    cid = 11;
    let err = null
    const response = await axios({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: BASE_URL + cid,
        data: inputs
    }).catch(e => err = e);

    console.log(response, 'was the response');
    return;
}
```

But on doing so, I am getting this error:

```
Error: Network Error
    createError createError.js:16
    handleError xhr.js:83
    dispatchXhrRequest xhr.js:80
    xhrAdapter xhr.js:12
    dispatchRequest dispatchRequest.js:52
    promise callback*request Axios.js:61
    wrap bind.js:9
    updateOne apiCalls.js:36
    js apiCalls.js:66
    Webpack 22
 was the response apiCalls.js:42
```

The Code can be found on GitHub : https://github.com/uinstinct/card_builder

**If you need more information, I shall provide what you need. Please a comment for the same**

Comment: Can you check in network tab. Whether api is hitting or not?

Comment: What is the value of `BASE_URL`, also in postman you are sending x-www-form-urlencoded but in your code it is a aplain js object.

Comment: @Reyno The value of `BASE_URL` is `http://localhost:9000/` and it is working fine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*After going through almost all the search results of this similar question, I figured out these:*

- Data from a redirected url ( *redirected by the backend itself* ) cannot be handled by any library - Be it axios or fetch or XMLHttpRequest itself

This cannot happen because the backend application ( *in this case: express* ) send `res.status.code` of `302` which basically tells the browser that : "the data, you are looking for, cannot be found in this url but in the url I am redirecting you to"

This code simply won't work in any library:

```js
app.get("/i/came/here",function(req,res){
 return res.redirect("/now/go/here"); // the actual data stored here
}
```

You might even get a CORS error

- If you trying to redirect to a url, that might not even work with axios or fetch unless you use an **interceptor** or some other kind of middleware or function to handle the handle error.

*Yes, axios will always throw an error whenever the backend tries to produce a redirect*

More on this here : https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/932#issuecomment-307390761

- There is no way ( that I found ) which can get the redirected data from the url
  axios will always be throwing an error when you try to do that.
  The best possible solution ( that I found ) is to handle the resultant data in the backend application itself.

For the particular problem dealt in this question, I changed the backend route *which updates a character* like this :

```js
router.put('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    Promise.all([
        updateAbilities(id, req.body.abilities, next),
        updateCharacter(id, req.body.name, req.body.img, next),
        updateShows(id, req.body.shows, next)
    ])
        .then(values => console.log(values, 'are the values received at put request'))
        .then(() => getOneById(id,res))
        .catch(err => next(err));
})
```

I used a function called `getOneById(id,res)` which handles the logic for getting the particular character and sending a json response.

I am welcome to all edits and suggestion. Please do correct if I am wrong.
*Please leave a comment below for the same*

Answer (score 0):

In Postman you send the data as `x-www-form-urlencoded`. Axios probably sends your data as JSON with a `content-type` of `application/json`. Is your express App able to handle json requests? You need to use bodyParser middleware:

Via npm:
`npm i body-parser`

In your app, you need to require it and then use the middleware:

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// ...
// ...
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Edit: as pointed out in the comments you can also use the express.json() middleware, which is the same.

`app.use(express.json());`

...without any installs.

Comment: Express has the `body-parser` build in, no need to install it. Just use `express.json()`

Comment: I don't think that it is a problem with body-parser because my post route is already working
Moreover, I have used body-parser already
```const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const routes = require('./routes');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Postman request makes use of `x-www-form-urlencoded` you need to convert your `inputs` object into an url encoded string.

Also change the axios content-type header to `x-www-form-urlencoded` since by default it is `application/json`

```
headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}
```

```js
const inputs = {
  name: "green latern 2",
  abilities: "ring, superpower",
  shows: "justice league",
  img: "an image",
};


const urlencoded = Object.entries(inputs).map(([key, value]) => {
  return encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
}).join("&");

console.log(urlencoded);
```

Comment: I really don't think it is a problem with json or url encoded because my post route is completely working. https://pastebin.com/0Nv8GE0d
I tried something else and got this error now : https://pasteboard.co/JnYB6N9.png

Comment: @uinstinct Seems like an error in your CORS settings. Your server needs to output the following header:  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:9000`

Comment: @uinstinct Also the `PUT` request and the `x-www-form-urlencoded` do not trigger the `OPTIONS` call which set the CORS headers. [More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8572637/3257622). Try adding the [morgan](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/morgan.html) middleware to see if the `OPTIONS` call is being made. `app.use(morgan("dev"))`

Comment: I don't think that there is a problem with the server itself
I think, the problem is with `axios` because the *the character* is updated in the database. This is means that the **request is successful but not the response**.
You can see for yourself [here](https://pasteboard.co/JnYNNDW.png)